# Object Already Loaded Error (360) Using .Net ActiveX control in VB6 project

Tags: .net, user-controls, vb6, activex, winforms-interop

I have created a .Net ActiveX control using the Forms Interop Toolkit.

When I used the control in a VB6 project I occasionally get the following error:

**Object Already Loaded (360)**.

This doesn't make much sense because this error only refers to object arrays that are loaded at runtime but my control is not in a control array is just sited on the form.

Comment: just wanted to answer your question, but you figured it out alreadyy :)

Comment: @lordkain - yes I couldn't find any reference to this on SO, so I decided to add this as a knowledgebase article

Comment: Self-answering does not eliminate the requirements on a question.  It must be properly documented, at least a repro snippet and the stack trace of the exception.  Clearly calling GC.Collect() is a hack that should always be avoided, nor does your answer actually explain the cause of the problem.  The odds you'll get a *good* answer are greatly diminished when you don't document properly.

Comment: @HansPassant - A Stack trace is not relevant here because the error is thrown in the VB6 project. I have merely posted one solution (I don't know why this happens!). If there are better suggestions/explanations as to why this happens I will gladly upvote / accept them.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I came across [this site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9174d48d-7461-449e-b0c0-f62c5a7fff59/object-already-loaded-error-in-interop-user-control?forum=vbinterop) which gave a solution:

Force garbage collection of the control after it is Disposed:

In the following method (generated by the Forms Interop Toolkit template):

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
```

There is a call to Dispose of the object. Add a line to force garbage collection:

```
ElseIf m.Msg = WM_DESTROY AndAlso Not Me.IsDisposed AndAlso Not Me.Disposing Then
    'Used to ensure that VB6 will cleanup control properly
    Me.Dispose()
    System.GC.Collect() '<-- Add this line
End If
```